# how do I put submit image inside input form of search bar?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a search bar in my website, as the image shows, I want to put that "go" image inside the "quick search" input bar. Is there any way I can do that through css?

[image: my search form]

Here's the code for that search bar part:

```
<div style="float:right; width:50%">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6" style="float:right">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group input-group-hg input-group-rounded">
        <asp:TextBox ID="searchBar" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Quick Search" Width="200" Height="30px" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" />   
      <span class="input-group-btn">
         <a href="#" id="search" style ="right:10px;"><img src="images/go.png" /></a>
      </span>             
    </div> <br />
          </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are a couple methods to do this:

1. You can add a negative margin-left to the CSS of the button to move it left enough that it appears inside the box.
2. You can use CSS to make an outer DIV appear like a text box with a border, and then inside you have a textbox with NO border, and the button. So visually it looks like the border of the DIV is the border of the textbox when in reality it is not.